# Magento Product definition with different prices for different regions

Tags: magento

I have an interesting problem that I need to get resolved.

I have a website with Magento shopping cart servicing different countries.  I was wondering if there is a way to create products in Magento in such a way that I could price them differently for different regions.  Namely:

```
Product 1     Region: US      Price: 100 USD
Product 1     Region: UK      Price: 80 GBP
```

I'd like to avoid duplicating the products in the catalog.  In addition the simple currency conversion won't work since there may be duties and other considerations involved in determining the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be awkward, but you could possibly build each product as configurable, and then the simple associated products could be the ones that are viewable in the various stores.

Probably not what you're after, but it could work with some elbow grease.

Aside from that, you'll need to set up multiple websites on the same installation. For that, start here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/

Answer (score 2):

in order to do this you'll need to configure multiple websites. Magento has one base currency per website, which means that all other currencies within that website are FX conversions from the original one.

So, for your example, if the base currency was USD then GBP would convert based on a rate from that original currency.

You can do some more reading here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/managing-currency/

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please Navigate to magento->admin->system->config->catalog-> and look for the field "Catalog Price Scope". This is what you may be looking for. As previous posts said you need to create multiple websites.