# Magento:Store View Based prices for Products

Tags: magento

There is already a feature in Magento 1.7 for Catalog Price Scope as "Website". Is there any solution to make Catalog Price Scope as "Store View" behave as a Store scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set the price scope to store view by default. You could write a custom extension to achieve this (or use one from Magento Connect), or create a separate website (store group) for the store you wish to have with products with different pricing.

Comment: Thanks james, I think creating another website is a good idea

Comment: @DushyantJoshi you're welcome. Would you mind selecting my answer if it is helpful ? :-)

Comment: Thanks james, helpful answer for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use this extension:

[Store View Pricing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing-3541.html).

It's free and for Magento 1.7

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Extension:

[StoreView Pricing](http://innoexts.com/store-view-pricing/#.UFGWqq6E_RQ)

It's free and work like a charm. I use this since 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

1) http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/320521/

2) [Magento Product definition with different prices for different regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913160/magento-product-definition-with-different-prices-for-different-regions)

and here is video how to do that - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/multiple-sites/

**Should be easy**

Comment: Thanks for sharing will have a look on that