# Magmi multi site import with Datapump API - different prices on same SKU-s

Tags: import, magento-1.7, magmi, datapump

The structure of project is 2 websites with same categories and same products.
The only difference is the price (basicly the second shop is something like wholesale).

So we have:
website A - language 1 & language 2 
website B - language 1 & language 2  (same as website A)

Import is working just fine but today client called me we have a problem!?.
Magento and Apache doesn't show any errors.
Problem is:
We can't update prices. (Video [here](http://youtu.be/O7J2Diy3efY) )

```
    $newProductData = array(
        'sku'           => "test123",
        'store'         => "veen,vehr",
        'qty'           => 1000,
        'price'         => 10
);
$dp->ingest($newProductData);

$newProductData = array(
        'sku'           => "test123",
        'store'         => "en,hr",
        'qty'           => 1000,
        'price'         => 5
);
$dp->ingest($newProductData);
```

<strike>Hmm, now looking at the code... Could it be problem in qty?</strike>

Comment: what is the scope defined for the price attribute magento side ?

Comment: price attribute is default from magento install.
There is no scope (at least not changeable like in other attributes [global, website,store view] )
Here is [screenshot](http://webshop.ferivico.hr/price.png)
Btw I tried to add: 'attribute_set' => 'default'

Comment: magento 1.7 has a specific setting for price scoping. by default it is set to "global". see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834772/magentostore-view-based-prices-for-products

Comment: You are absolutely  right. It was set to global!
Funny, with magmi it changed for specific stores but unable to save in admin.
For everyone having problems with this:
In the Admin panel, goto System, Configuration, Catalog, then Price.
Change Price from Global to Website.
(Note: Magento saves this change for a long time. Be patient )

So simple (facepalm).