# Magento 1.9; Price per currency

Tags: magento, currency, magento-1.9

I'm working for a client which has 3 websites and multiple storeviews each. For some reason he really wants to have 3 currencies and each currency it's own price per product.

So a product can cost i.e. €49,99 / $55,- / £39,95 and these prices have to be configured for each product. To clarify: There is no relation between the prices so it can't be done with an exact percentage. Prices need to differ completely.

I've found "solutions" to make 3 separate websites with each a different price for a product, but seeing as there are already 3 websites, I'd need 9 and that's just out of the question.

Also I found extensions like this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/currency-pricing.html - all of 'm don't work with 1.9 and especially work worse with configurable products, which happens to be the case here.

I'm really out of ideas, anyone else got a possible fix for this?

**Update 06-2016** I get quite some mails about this question, if I ever found a fix or some other solution; sadly no. I did do further investigation about it and found out that this concept goes against the core-logic of the Magento (multi)store. We've now begun to work with Magento2 and will evaluate again if it is easier in this version. If I ever get to something, I'll update the question here.

Comment: Sounds like you know most of the possible solutions already, this other question basically asking the same thing had an [interesting alternative option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8917170/1737136) you could consider.

Comment: That is, sadly, no longer an option for these stores. After further investigation we found out there wasn't such an option in Magento, and we might create a module to add this functionality ourselves.

Answer (score -2):

There is no fix.
I think you need an own magento for every currency cause PRODUCTS ONLY USE ONE PRICE. Sadly..

Comment: Uhm, yeah. That's the conclusion I gave in my OP, this isn't an answer to the original question.

Comment: To answer your question: There is no fix.